# Not able to push data into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to get to the logic of the Tic Tac Toe game which I almost have made a logic, but I am stuck while pushing the Data to the array. Here is a fiddle that I have created.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/6bgjp/1/

Let me explain the whole thing to you!

I am trying to use the 9 td of the table as the 8 rows of the possible win. For that I have given some of the tds a className depending on their location in the table.

The HTML is simple

```
<div class="vicvacvoe">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="line1 line4 line7"></td>
            <td class="line1 line5"></td>
            <td class="line1 line6 line8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="line2 line4"></td>
            <td class="line2 line5 line7 line8"></td>
            <td class="line2 line6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="line3 line4 line8"></td>
            <td class="line3 line5"></td>
            <td class="line3 line6 line7"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Just a simple table with 9 tds, the CSS is not relative to this so leave it I guess.

jQuery for this also simple one. But I am not able to push the data to the Array.

```
var vic = $('.vicvacvoe table tr td');
    var player = 1;
    var tick = '✓';
    var cross = 'X';
    var user1 = [];
    var user2 = [];
    vic.click(function () {
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        if (className != 'dead') {
            // A new board place to write on...
            // Now do the processes here...
            if (player == 1) {
                // First player!
                var cArray = className.split(' ');
                for (i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < user1.length; j++) {
                        // check for each class
                        if (user1[j] != cArray[i]) {
                            user1.push(cArray[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /* code for second player, the same */
            }
            $(this).text('Works!');
            $(this).attr('class', 'dead');
        }
    });
```

This is the entire jQuery script. Actually when I run the code, it really does go to the end of the stack (to the class attribute change script) and it locks the td for further process and it write **Works!** in the td too. But I am not able to get the classNames inside the Array for that user. I want to save the line number for each user and then check whether he has 3 spots filled or not. I need help with the Array part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
for (j = 0; j < user1.length; j++) {
```

The only place you add to the `user1` array is within this loop.  Now the array is initially empty, so clearly this loop will never iterate as `user1.length` is always 0.

I think your intent with this bit of code was to check if the value was already in the array in which case I suggest using [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/).

Comment: Oh, I never came up with that! Ummm or instead of that, just a length check using `if(user1.lenght != 0) {` ? What would be better in your opinion? :)

Comment: If you are as I'm guessing, trying to check for the existence in the array, I would use `inarray`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer simplicity so you could use `indexOf` to check whether the class is already in the users' array like so:

```
if (player == 1) {
     // First player!
     var cArray = className.split(' ');
     for (i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
          if(user1.indexOf(cArray[i]) == -1) {
               user1.push(cArray[i]);
          } else {
               // css class is already in the array              
          }
     }
}
```